# How to make points with label info in ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: c#, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm a new user of the Arcgis for Silverlight SDK.  Using c#, I would like to add points with labels showing the id for point.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Surely there is API documentation available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the [Silverlight samples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm) in the Esri Silverlight help. One in particular, [Using PointDataSource](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm#UsingPointDataSource), contains the code to add points to the map that have a MapTip.